# How can I display date in a wbpage using javascript in mozilla firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I just want to display the current date, month and year in my webpage in labels. This works fine in Google Chrome. It is shown below:
[image]

Now, when I open the same page in Firefox, the same labels are displayed as shown below:
[image]

I used JavaScript to get these dates and here is my code:

```
 <label id="Label3">Accounting Year:  </label><label id="Label4" name="Label4">Label4</label><label id="Label5">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Accounting Month: </label>
    <label id="Label6" name="Label6">Label6</label> <label id="Label7">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Enquiry Date: </label>
    <label id="Label8" name="Label8">label8</label><br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var year = new Date();
    var yearonly = year.getFullYear();
    var nextyear = yearonly+1;
    Label4.innerText = yearonly.toString()+"-"+nextyear.toString();

var month=['January' , 'February' ,'March', 'April' , 'May' ,'June', 'July' , 'August' ,'September', 'October' , 'November' ,'December'];
    var n = month[year.getMonth()];
    Label6.innerText = n.toString()+" "+yearonly.toString();

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy= today.getFullYear();
    Label8.innerText=dd.toString()+"-"+mm.toString()+"-"+yyyy.toString();
</script>
```

Is there any problem with my code?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `innerText`? try `textContent` instead and see if it fixes things.

Comment: Have tried ``innerHTML``?

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked. I used textContent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use textContent instead of innerText

http://jsbin.com/doyuciyi/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementById('Label').innerHTML  = yourText;` to get your element you want to change.

For me it works like this. You can see it in my demo. http://jsfiddle.net/VVHex/